# How to put a shortcut to a folder or subfolder in Documents by Readdle | My Files | Files | Foo | Bar onto my iPhone's home screen?

Tags: iphone, filesystem

I'm using an iPhone XR running iOS 14.6. How can I put a shortcut on my home screen to a folder or subfolder that I currently access by clicking on Documents and then going My Files | Files | Foo | Bar ?

I am looking for a solution that does not require using the cloud, a Google account, or Siri.

Comment: As far as I know, you can‘t do that. You can only do things in *iCloud* or *Dropbox*. As example create a folder or a file with ir without content. But what do you want to do in this *folder/subfolder*?

Comment: In answer to your q: I have a folder for some .doc files and another for .pdf files, that I can get to from the home screen by going Documents (this is an icon for the prog by Readdle) and then Files | Ruffle's Folder | Ruffdocs and then I have one folder for .docs and another for .pdfs. The .docs I read and sometimes work on. The .pdfs are mainly for showing people. So it's just standard computer-user stuff - nothing out of the ordinary - but opening the files currently requires a lot of clicks. I don't understand your third sentence.